# What could be the reason for consumer of JMS queue being unable to read and returns error: Not authorised?

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic

Error message:

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic://XXX.XXX' - trying to recover. Cause: User <XXXX> is not authorized to read from: topic://xxxx.xxxx
```

The URL is correct. The user/password is correct. The certificate file is present. What else can I check to understand the issue?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the user is "not **authorized**." In other words, the user doesn't have *permission* to read from the specified topic. This can happen even if the credentials (i.e. user, password, certificate) allow successful authentication since authentication and authorization are separate (but related) concerns.

You'll need to check the authorization configuration for whatever JMS broker you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
Indeed it was something to do with JMS configuration.
The topic was published as XXX., while we were trying to connect to YYY.

The error was misleading.
Thanks